# How To Codesign App Created from Pyinstaller for Catalina Distribution

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller, macos-catalina, codesign

I'm having a problem notarizing and distributing app packaged from pyinstaller to Catalina.

In my entitlements.plist, I set com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit and com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory to true.

I also tried setting com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation. However, if I do that, I can't even open it. It just asks me to trash it.

Here's my command for code signing.

`codesign --deep --force --options runtime --entitlements entitlements.plist --sign "$DEVELOPER" "$APP.app" --timestamp`

When I open, I get this.

```
[1276] Error loading Python lib '/var/folders/kb/ww5w7w_s45139t2n329cr3lw0000gn/T/_MEI3Jv8Ln/libpython3.7m.dylib': dlopen: dlopen(/var/folders/kb/ww5w7w_s45139t2n329cr3lw0000gn/T/_MEI3Jv8Ln/libpython3.7m.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /var/folders/kb/ww5w7w_s45139t2n329cr3lw0000gn/T/_MEI3Jv8Ln/libpython3.7m.dylib: code signature in (/var/folders/kb/ww5w7w_s45139t2n329cr3lw0000gn/T/_MEI3Jv8Ln/libpython3.7m.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
    /var/folders/kb/ww5w7w_s45139t2n329cr3lw0000gn/T/_MEI3Jv8Ln/libpython3.7m.dylib: stat() failed with errno=3
```

I also tried `codesign -f -s "$DEVELOPER" /path/to/libpython3.7m.dylib` before running pyinstaller, but then I got "Killed: 9" when I run the app in Catalina machine.

It works fine if I don't codesign and force allow from system preference > security for it to run.

I'd like to be able to distribute normally without users having to do that though.

Comment: Any luck? I have the exact same problem and can't find any information. Thanks!